# I want to install Ubuntu on a new desktop computer build

Tags: software-installation

I'm just about to finish building a new desktop.  The graphics card in due to be delivered today.  Before I set the BIOS I want to find out what steps I need to take to install Ubuntu.  I'm not interested at this time in a dual boot machine. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I install Ubuntu?](/q/6328)

Answer (score 0):

You simply download an Ubuntu image from the Ubuntu website, write that to a USB drive(`dd if=/path/to/iso of=/dev/sdX bs=16M` where `/dev/sdX` is your flash drive)(or disc if you want).

You then boot off this flash drive(flash drive => default boot device) Then you remove it and restart(booting off hard disk)

Comment: No problem :) If my answer answers your question, please mark it as correct(click the tick). Thanks in advance and welcome to AskUbuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you need more detailed instructions, [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) are good references.

I'm aware that just providing links is frowned upon, but this is the ubuntu documentation to answer this question, and it's incredibly long, and changes.

Comment: Nice of you to provide links, but I'd recommend at least providing the main idea in the body as I have done.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a USB drive (4GB will do nicely) and a program to create a bootable USB stick from an iso (I recommend Rufus).

Download the Ubuntu .iso here

Once downloaded, run Rufus with your USB drive plugged in. Select the USB drive in the Device menu, click on the little disk image button next to the Create a bootable disk using and select the iso you just downloaded. Then click start. It will ask you if you really want to format the drive, which you need to do, so make sure there's no important info on it. Rufus will take about 7 minutes to complete (on my system anyway).

Boot off of the USB drive

Once the USB loads, click any button, then select the language. You now have several options Ubuntu Live Install Boot Menu

You can either Install right away or Try Ubuntu and then install. Once you decide to install, Ubuntu will give you the instructions you need.

Comment: Hey Everyone,  thank you for the helpful replies!  I ended up burning an image to dvd and booting from that.  Easy.  Then connected to internet an ran updates.  I am so pleased with this installation.  I know I'm going to enjoy learning the intricacies of Ubuntu.  Next will be getting a firewall set.